# ORA-01841 error : year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

I have a plsql block and I'm getting "ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0" error. My where clause is like;

```
WHERE TO_DATE(MK.CREATE_DATE||'-01','YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN trunc(add_months(trunc(sysdate),-1),'MM') and trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1
```

and `mk.create_date format` is '2020-01','2020-02' exc.

My point is getting last month's values.

Is there anybody to help me?
Thank you

Comment: Apparently, not all values in CREATE_DATE have a valid **year** value as the first 4 characters. Find & fix them.

Comment: Also feel free to get rid of the `between`, you are creating the first day of month from `create_date` so comparison with first day of the last month will suffice. And why to convert `CREATE_DATE` to date when you can convert the other side (and possibly keep index on CREATE_DATE working, even better would be to store `CREATE_DATE` as `DATE` column in the first place ). 

`WHERE MK.CREATE_DATE = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'YYYY-MM')`

Comment: Your conversion does not need the concatenation. Just use `to_date(mk.create_date,'yyyy-mm')` 
But I will echo @Petr, **always store date values as DATE (or TIMESTAMP)**. 
Then  virtually everything you want to do can be done without converting to a string, except to display them is a specific format. See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=63cb0ebf2c96fd6608c3f471ae0d8542).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on conversion error` as follows to get rid of corrupt data(oracle 12.2 or higher).

```
TO_DATE(MK.CREATE_DATE||'-01','YYYY-MM-DD' default null on conversion error)
```